# AngularJS and Require: r.js gives undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I understand there's some debate about whether or not to use require.js with AngularJS, but I am doing so at this time.  I have the whole project set up and running with require, and am now attempting to use r.js to optimize and minify.

After running r.js and changing my `data-main` in my `index.html` file, I am now getting that `angular is undefined` and cannot proceed.

I was able to reproduce the same behavior using the [angular-require-seed](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed).  I followed the instructions on github to install and then made the following build definition for r.js.

**build.js**

```
({
    baseUrl: "./app/js",
    name: "main",
    out: "index-built.js",
    paths: {
       angular: '../../bower_components/angular/angular',
       'angular-scenario': '../../bower_components/angular-scenario/angular-scenario',
       'angularRoute': '../../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route',
       'angular-mocks': '../../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks'
   }    
})
```

I then ran r.js using the following command at the top level of the app.

```
r.js.cmd -o build.js
```

Once `r.js` completed I changed the `data-main` in index.html to be `data-main="index-built.js"`

This is once again resulting in angular being `undefined`.  Can anyone point me to the error of my ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you [remembering to shim](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed/blob/master/app/js/main.js#L9) the library?

If you are then you will also need to include that same config in your `build.js`. The best way to do this is point [the `mainConfigFile` property](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L27) at your `main.js` and let it pick up the config values from there (including the paths above too).

Comment: Ah I had assumed that it would automatically include the shims that I had defined when it was doing the build.  Thanks for the info!